# Instruments - suppress allocations from a specific "responsible caller"

Tags: ios, profiling, instruments, memory-profiling

I'm trying to profile an app and one of the underlying libraries is "contaminating" my results, so to speak. Specifically this library is OpenSSL. We are aware of the issues it has and are trying to profile other areas of our app, however we tend to have to sift through piles of this:

[image: garbage]

I'm looking for a way to have instruments suppress leaks/allocations coming from that specific "Responsible Caller" `CRYPTO_malloc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think you can filter out only `CRYPTO_malloc`, but you can filter on the basis of what you are interested in. For example, if your app was called `MyApp`, just enter that down in the [filter and configuration bar](https://help.apple.com/instruments/mac/current/#/devadf729aef):

[image]